# Opencart Fatal Error with Automatic SEO Title

Tags: php, module, opencart, fatal-error, vqmod

I i have installed top Module following the steps provided by the producer, the module installs successfully but then i get a fatal error saying.

**Fatal error: Call to undefined method ControllerModuleAutoSeoTitle::render() in /home/clockworksignage/public_html/admin/controller/module/autoseotitle.php on line 166**

Please see the code below for the autoseo title.php

This is line 166

```
$this->response->setOutput($this->render());
```

This is the entire file

```
    <?php
class ControllerModuleAutoSeoTitle extends Controller {
    private $error = array();
    public function index() {
        $this->load->language('module/autoseotitle');
        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('ast_title'));
        $this->load->model('setting/setting');

        if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
            $arr_ast = array('ast_custom' => $this->request->post['ast_custom'], 'ast_custom1' => $this->request->post['ast_custom1'], 'ast_custom2' => $this->request->post['ast_custom2'], 'ast_sep' => implode(',', $this->request->post['ast_sep']), 'ast_ssep' => implode(',', $this->request->post['ast_ssep']), 'ast_hsep' => implode(',', $this->request->post['ast_hsep']), 'ast_order' => implode(',', $this->request->post['ast_order']), 'ast_sorder' => implode(',', $this->request->post['ast_sorder']), 'ast_horder' => implode(',', $this->request->post['ast_horder']));
            $this->model_setting_setting->editSetting('autoseotitle', $arr_ast);        
            $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('ast_success_text');
            $this->redirect($this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'));
        }

        if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
            $this->data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
        } else if (isset($this->session->data['error']) ) {
            $this->data['error_warning'] = $this->session->data['error'];
            unset($this->session->data['error']);
        }
        else {
            $this->data['error_warning'] = '';
        }

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text'      => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href'      => $this->url->link('common/home', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'),
            'separator' => false
        );

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text'      => $this->language->get('text_module'),
            'href'      => $this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'),
            'separator' => ' :: '
        );

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text'      => $this->language->get('ast_title'),
            'href'      => $this->url->link('module/autoseotitle', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'),
            'separator' => ' :: '
        );

        $this->data['button_save'] = $this->language->get('ast_save');
        $this->data['button_cancel'] = $this->language->get('ast_cancel');

        if (isset($this->request->post['ast_custom'])) {
            $this->data['ast_custom'] = $this->request->post['ast_custom'];
        } else {
            $this->data['ast_custom'] = $this->config->get('ast_custom');
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['ast_custom1'])) {
            $this->data['ast_custom1'] = $this->request->post['ast_custom1'];
        } else {
            $this->data['ast_custom1'] = $this->config->get('ast_custom1');
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['ast_custom2'])) {
            $this->data['ast_custom2'] = $this->request->post['ast_custom2'];
        } else {
            $this->data['ast_custom2'] = $this->config->get('ast_custom2');
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['ast_order'])) {
            $this->data['ast_order'] = $this->request->post['ast_order'];
        } else {
            $this->data['ast_order'] = explode(",", $this->config->get('ast_order'));
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['ast_sorder'])) {
            $this->data['ast_sorder'] = $this->request->post['ast_sorder'];
        } else {
            $this->data['ast_sorder'] = explode(",", $this->config->get('ast_sorder'));
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['ast_horder'])) {
            $this->data['ast_horder'] = $this->request->post['ast_horder'];
        } else {
            $this->data['ast_horder'] = explode(",", $this->config->get('ast_horder'));
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['ast_sep'])) {
            $this->data['ast_sep'] = $this->request->post['ast_sep'];
        } else {
            $this->data['ast_sep'] = explode(",", $this->config->get('ast_sep'));
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['ast_ssep'])) {
            $this->data['ast_ssep'] = $this->request->post['ast_ssep'];
        } else {
            $this->data['ast_ssep'] = explode(",", $this->config->get('ast_ssep'));
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['ast_hsep'])) {
            $this->data['ast_hsep'] = $this->request->post['ast_hsep'];
        } else {
            $this->data['ast_hsep'] = explode(",", $this->config->get('ast_hsep'));
        }

        $this->data['action'] = $this->url->link('module/autoseotitle', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');
        $this->data['cancel'] = $this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');
        $this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('ast_title');
        $this->data['description'] = $this->language->get('ast_description');
        $this->data['entry_sitename'] = $this->language->get('ast_entry_sitename');
        $this->data['entry_sitename_description'] = $this->language->get('ast_entry_sitename_description');
        $this->data['entry_brandname'] = $this->language->get('ast_entry_brandname');
        $this->data['entry_brandname_description'] = $this->language->get('ast_entry_brandname_description');
        $this->data['entry_price'] = $this->language->get('ast_entry_price');
        $this->data['entry_price_description'] = $this->language->get('ast_entry_price_description');
        $this->data['entry_special'] = $this->language->get('ast_entry_special');
        $this->data['entry_special_description'] = $this->language->get('ast_entry_special_description');
        $this->data['entry_order'] = $this->language->get('ast_entry_order');
        $this->data['entry_order_description'] = $this->language->get('ast_entry_order_description');
        $this->data['entry_sorder'] = $this->language->get('ast_entry_sorder');
        $this->data['entry_sorder_description'] = $this->language->get('ast_entry_sorder_description');
        $this->data['entry_horder'] = $this->language->get('ast_entry_horder');
        $this->data['entry_horder_description'] = $this->language->get('ast_entry_horder_description');
        $this->data['entry_cat'] = $this->language->get('ast_entry_cat');
        $this->data['entry_cat_description'] = $this->language->get('ast_entry_cat_description');
        $this->data['entry_separator'] = $this->language->get('ast_entry_separator');
        $this->data['entry_separator_description'] = $this->language->get('ast_entry_separator_description');
        $this->data['entry_custom'] = $this->language->get('ast_entry_custom');
        $this->data['entry_custom_description'] = $this->language->get('ast_entry_custom_description');
        $this->data['entry_custom1'] = $this->language->get('ast_entry_custom1');
        $this->data['entry_custom1_description'] = $this->language->get('ast_entry_custom1_description');
        $this->data['entry_custom2'] = $this->language->get('ast_entry_custom2');
        $this->data['entry_custom2_description'] = $this->language->get('ast_entry_custom2_description');
        $this->data['entry_example'] = $this->language->get('ast_entry_example');
        $this->data['entry_example_description'] = $this->language->get('ast_entry_example_description');
        $this->data['yes'] = $this->language->get('ast_yes');
        $this->data['no'] = $this->language->get('ast_no');
        $this->data['order_pagename'] = $this->language->get('ast_order_pagename');
        $this->data['order_sitename'] = $this->language->get('ast_order_sitename');
        $this->data['order_brand'] = $this->language->get('ast_order_brand');
        $this->data['order_price'] = $this->language->get('ast_order_price');
        $this->data['order_model'] = $this->language->get('ast_order_model');
        $this->data['order_special'] = $this->language->get('ast_order_special');
        $this->data['order_product'] = $this->language->get('ast_order_product');
        $this->data['order_cat'] = $this->language->get('ast_order_cat');
        $this->data['order_custom'] = $this->language->get('ast_order_custom');
        $this->data['order_custom1'] = $this->language->get('ast_order_custom1');
        $this->data['order_custom2'] = $this->language->get('ast_order_custom2');
        $this->data['order_nothing'] = $this->language->get('ast_order_nothing');

        $this->data['modules'] = array();

        if (isset($this->request->post['autoseotitle_module'])) {
            $this->data['modules'] = $this->request->post['autoseotitle_module'];
        } else { 
            $this->data['modules'] = $this->config->get('autoseotitle_module');
        }

        $this->load->model('design/layout');

        $this->data['layouts'] = $this->model_design_layout->getLayouts();

        $this->template = 'module/autoseotitle.tpl';
        $this->children = array(
            'common/header',
            'common/footer'
        );

        $this->response->setOutput($this->render());

    }

    private function validate() {
        if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'module/autoseotitle')) {
            $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('ast_error_access');
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['autoseotitle_module'])) {
            foreach ($this->request->post['autoseotitle_module'] as $key => $value) {               

            }
        }   

        if (!$this->error) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }   
    }

    public function install() {
        $vqmod_xml_dir = substr_replace(DIR_SYSTEM, '/vqmod/xml/', -8);
        rename($vqmod_xml_dir . 'auto-seo-title-vqmod.xml_', $vqmod_xml_dir . 'auto-seo-title-vqmod.xml');
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO ". DB_PREFIX . "setting VALUES (NULL,'". (int)$this->config->get('store_admin') ."','autoseotitle','ast_custom','','0')");
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO ". DB_PREFIX . "setting VALUES (NULL,'". (int)$this->config->get('store_admin') ."','autoseotitle','ast_custom1','','0')");
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO ". DB_PREFIX . "setting VALUES (NULL,'". (int)$this->config->get('store_admin') ."','autoseotitle','ast_custom2','','0')");
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO ". DB_PREFIX . "setting VALUES (NULL,'". (int)$this->config->get('store_admin') ."','autoseotitle','ast_order','0,4,2,5,3,6,1,0','0')");
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO ". DB_PREFIX . "setting VALUES (NULL,'". (int)$this->config->get('store_admin') ."','autoseotitle','ast_sorder','0,1,2','0')");
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO ". DB_PREFIX . "setting VALUES (NULL,'". (int)$this->config->get('store_admin') ."','autoseotitle','ast_horder','0,1,2','0')");
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO ". DB_PREFIX . "setting VALUES (NULL,'". (int)$this->config->get('store_admin') ."','autoseotitle','ast_sep',', - , - , - , - , - ,','0')");
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO ". DB_PREFIX . "setting VALUES (NULL,'". (int)$this->config->get('store_admin') ."','autoseotitle','ast_ssep',', - ','0')");
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO ". DB_PREFIX . "setting VALUES (NULL,'". (int)$this->config->get('store_admin') ."','autoseotitle','ast_hsep',', - ','0')");
    }

    public function uninstall() {
        $vqmod_xml_dir = substr_replace(DIR_SYSTEM, '/vqmod/xml/', -8);
        rename($vqmod_xml_dir . 'auto-seo-title-vqmod.xml', $vqmod_xml_dir . 'auto-seo-title-vqmod.xml_');
        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "setting WHERE `key` = 'ast_custom'");
        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "setting WHERE `key` = 'ast_custom1'");
        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "setting WHERE `key` = 'ast_custom2'");
        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "setting WHERE `key` = 'ast_order'");
        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "setting WHERE `key` = 'ast_sorder'");
        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "setting WHERE `key` = 'ast_horder'");
        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "setting WHERE `key` = 'ast_sep'");
        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "setting WHERE `key` = 'ast_ssep'");
        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "setting WHERE `key` = 'ast_hsep'");
    }

}
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Many Thanks
Sam

Comment: `render()`? in a controller? shouldn't that sort of thing be in a view?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of opencart you are using?

What I'm thinking is that you're using version 2.0+ while this module is written on opencart 1.5+ architecture. If that is the case then you have to make few changes in controllers viz.

`$this->data['action'] = $this->url->link('module/autoseotitle', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');`

into

`$data['action'] = $this->url->link('module/autoseotitle', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');`

Basically change `$this->data[' ']` to `$data[' ']` whenever you are storing values to be passed to the template.

Again while calling the tpl file you may have to change it from

```
$this->template = 'module/autoseotitle.tpl';
        $this->children = array(
            'common/header',
            'common/footer'
        );

        $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
```

to

```
$data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
$data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
$data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');

$this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('module/autoseotitle.tpl', $data));
```